# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).show(...).revolution is not a function - Laravel 8

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I get the following, "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).show(...).revolution is not a function
When I run my Laravel Project.
I have tried loading Jquery from CDN and trying to change the sequence of how they load, but I get the same error.
The result of this error is that all the divs with revolution sliders fail to load.

[image: Snip of the console error]

revolution.js

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery('#rev_slider_4').show().revolution({
          dottedOverlay: 'none',
          delay: 5000,
          startwidth: 1170,
          startheight:720,
          hideThumbs: 200,
          thumbWidth: 200,
          thumbHeight: 50,
          thumbAmount: 2,
          navigationType: 'thumb',
          navigationArrows: 'solo',
          navigationStyle: 'round',
          touchenabled: 'on',
          onHoverStop: 'on',
          swipe_velocity: 0.7,
          swipe_min_touches: 1,
          swipe_max_touches: 1,
          drag_block_vertical: false,
          spinner: 'spinner0',
          keyboardNavigation: 'off',
          navigationHAlign: 'center',
          navigationVAlign: 'bottom',
          navigationHOffset: 0,
          navigationVOffset: 20,
          soloArrowLeftHalign: 'left',
          soloArrowLeftValign: 'center',
          soloArrowLeftHOffset: 20,
          soloArrowLeftVOffset: 0,
          soloArrowRightHalign: 'right',
          soloArrowRightValign: 'center',
          soloArrowRightHOffset: 20,
          soloArrowRightVOffset: 0,
          shadow: 0,
          fullWidth: 'on',
          fullScreen: 'off',
          stopLoop: 'off',
          stopAfterLoops: -1,
          stopAtSlide: -1,
          shuffle: 'off',
          autoHeight: 'off',
          forceFullWidth: 'on',
          fullScreenAlignForce: 'off',
          minFullScreenHeight: 0,
          hideNavDelayOnMobile: 1500,
          hideThumbsOnMobile: 'off',
          hideBulletsOnMobile: 'off',
          hideArrowsOnMobile: 'off',
          hideThumbsUnderResolution: 0,
          hideSliderAtLimit: 0,
          hideCaptionAtLimit: 0,
          hideAllCaptionAtLilmit: 0,
          startWithSlide: 0,
          fullScreenOffsetContainer: ''
              });
     });
```

app.blade.php

```
    <!-- <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script> 
    <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap-select.min.js')}}"></script> 
    <script src="{{asset('js/parallax.js')}}"></script> 
    <script src="{{asset('js/revslider.js')}}"></script> 
    <script src="{{asset('js/common.js')}}"></script> 
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.bxslider.min.js')}}"></script> 
    <script src="{{asset('js/owl.carousel.min.js')}}"></script> 
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.mobile-menu.min.js')}}"></script> 
    <script src="{{asset('js/countdown.js')}}"></script> 
    <script src="{{asset('js/revolution.js')}}"></script>  
    <script src="{{asset('js/hideme.js')}}"></script> 
    <!-- Hot Deals Timer 1--> 
    <script src="{{asset('js/countback.js')}}"></script>
```

I would like your help to get the revolution slider working.

Comment: create a function `revolution` and add your values, then call `jQuery('#rev_slider_4').show().revolution();`

Comment: I have not caught you Dean, could you show me with an example of what you mean

Comment: There is no function on your script called revolution(), you need someting like function revolution(){}

Comment: Are you sure that, revolution.js has extended over jQuery? Because show() method returns jQuery instance.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and in my case, it was being caused by including jQuery twice.

Make sure that you have not included jQuery twice. Check all the scripts that are included on your page and ensure that none of them is including jquery already.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your whole .blade file? If that's the case, the problem is most likely that it can't find an element with the `id`: rev_slider_4. If you do have an element on your page, make sure the element has the right `id`.

You could also test if your other JavaScript works to make sure it's not a loading issue.